# Максимально приближенное число (Умная выбока sql)

Tags: php, sql

друзья помогите решить задачу, мне нужно из доступных данных выбрать значение и если оно не находит из существующих то привязать к максимально приблеженному тарифу  , есть некие данные (они могут меняться то что я написал для примера то есть показывать больше 5 или меньше не имеет смыла )

```
id interval_from  interval_to percent
1      5              100        2
2      101            200         3
3      201            400         5
```

к примеру если пришла сумма 150 все понятно у нас срабатывает 2 тарифный план ,

но что делать если пришла сумма 2 или же пришла сумма 1000  они не входят не из один тарифный план и 2 мне нужно привязать к 1 тарифному плану а 1000 к последнему , то есть задача что любую сумму мне нужно подвязать к тарифному плану , 
подскажите как сделать парвильную выборку ?

Comment: ну какой нить минимум модуля разности то не подойдет вам?

Comment: – teran  не совсем понял за какой  модуль вы говорите ?

Comment: математический модуль `|x|` или `abs(x)`

Comment: *что делать если пришла сумма 2 или же пришла сумма 1000* Для "первой" и "последней" записей откорректировать границы. Для "первой" interval_from = 0, для последней interval_to = максимальному для типа данных поля.

Comment: – Akina та в этом и проблема это некий конструктор для пользователей и пользователя не заставишь написать как мне нужно я должен оттолкнуться от того что есть , подожду  может будут еще какие то варианты

Comment: добавить строку `401, 99999999, 5` то нельзя, как @Akina говорит? это размер скидки какой-нибудь у вас?

Comment: *пользователя не заставишь написать как мне нужно* Это должен делать программный интерфейс. А пользователя надо просто поставить в известность, что его значения будут изменены в соответствии с требованиями.

Comment: Альтернативно - корректировать эти значения в запросе. Однако это будет геморройнее. А конкретная реализация зависит от используемой СУБД и её версии.